How to use server components in Client components Nextjs
I am trying to call the signup function defined my actions.ts (a server action) from a form on client side but I face the same error:
You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.
import { lucia } from "@/auth";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { signUpSchema, SignUpValues } from "@/lib/validation";
import { hash } from "@node-rs/argon2";
import { generateIdFromEntropySize } from "lucia";
import { isRedirectError } from "next/dist/client/components/redirect";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function signUp(
  credentials: SignUpValues
): Promise<{ error: string }> {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = signUpSchema.parse(credentials);

    const passwordHash = await hash(password, {
        // recommended minimum parameters
        memoryCost: 19456,
        timeCost: 2,
        outputLen: 32,
        parallelism: 1
    });
    const userId = generateIdFromEntropySize(10); // 16 characters long

    const existingUsername = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where:{
            username:{
                equals: username,
                mode: "insensitive"
            }
        }
    });

    if (existingUsername){
        return {error: "Username already taken"}
    }

    const existingEmail = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where:{
            username:{
                equals: email,
                mode: "insensitive"
            }
        }
    });

    if (existingEmail){
        return {error: "Email already taken"}
    }

    await prisma.user.create({
        data:{
            id: userId,
            username: username,
            displayName: username,
            email: email,
            passwordHash: passwordHash
        }
    })

    const session = await lucia.createSession(userId, {});
    const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);
    cookies().set(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value, sessionCookie.attributes);
    return redirect("/");


  } catch (error) {
    if (isRedirectError(error)) throw error;
    console.log(error);
    return{
        error: "Something went wrong. Please try again"
    }
  }
}



I am calling it from SignupForm.tsx (that I will later call in my page.tsx)
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
"use client";

// import LoadingButton from "@/components/LoadingButton";
// import { PasswordInput } from "@/components/PasswordInput";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { signUpSchema, SignUpValues } from "@/lib/validation";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useState, useTransition } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { signUp } from "./actions";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

export default function SignUpForm() {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>();

  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const form = useForm<SignUpValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(signUpSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(values: SignUpValues) {
    setError(undefined);
    startTransition(async () => {
      const { error } = await signUp(values);
      if (error) setError(error);
    });
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-3">
        {error && <p className="text-center text-destructive">{error}</p>}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="username"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Username" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Email" type="email" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Password" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
          Create account
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
  
}


I don't understand where is the problem since I have already done things similar and it's the first time I faced this error

First, it would be nice to know which one is the Server Component you want to include. Second, there is a mismatch between your action code shown here and the call to the server action (login vs signup). Please clean it up and let us know when it is done

@grekier it's done.
Please @ me if you need any more information

I don't think this is due to the server action but one of the components that you import is a server component. Can you check them all and tell us if any of them are?

@grekier nope none of them is (if you are talking of the SignupForm.tsx imports)
The action.ts and signupform are both in src/app/signup
